# Why do Minions want to serve vicious villains?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, despicable-me, despicable-me-2, minions

[From wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minions_(film)) about *Minions*:

> Minions are small, yellow creatures who have existed since the
>   beginning of time, evolving from single-celled organisms into beings
>   who exist only to serve history's most villainous masters

[From the *Despicable Me* wikia](http://despicableme.wikia.com/wiki/Minions)

> Personality
>
> They are fiercely loyal to Gru and Dr. Nefario and
>   extremely eager to please, willingly helping with any evil plans, but
>   at the same time they are friendly and fun-loving. Despite being
>   relatively simple-minded, they are capable of building weapons,
>   operating those weapons, using computers, and even driving.

So after reading many materials I understood that Minions are created to be funny and extremely stupid. From the creators [there is a quote](http://www.thewrap.com/minions-creator-pierre-coffin-on-why-theres-no-female-characters-in-the-animated-hit/) that says

> Seeing how dumb and stupid they often are, I just couldn’t imagine
>   Minions being girls.

So they are created as **cute, funny, dumb, stupid**. Then why do they want to serve evil masters? I can't seem to be find any answer regarding this. Searched in many interviews in Youtube. But didn't find any explanation.

Even in the origin story inside the Minions movie there is no explanation why they want to serve vicious villains. Why not a good people?!

When Scarlet wanted to hurt Stuart, Bob & Kevin, even then they acted as loyal and went to tell her 'Sorry'. Is there any explanation from the authors and creators why they don't serve good people and serve/want only villains? This just doesn't add up with their characters.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The simplest answer is that we learn (in the Minions movie) that that's how they evolved. Fish gotta swim, birds gotta fly, **minions gotta serve an evil master.**

The licensed [junior novel](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Minions-Junior-Novel-Movie/dp/1910114278) puts it quite nicely:

> Minions have been on this earth since the beginning of time. At first,
>   they were just shapeless, single-celled organisms searching for the
>   biggest, baddest villain to serve. **They’d follow anyone despicable
>   enough — as they needed to be led by something bigger than
>   themselves.**
>
> Over hundreds of years, the Minions evolved, growing arms and legs. As
>   they evolved, so did their choice of leader. Each master was
>   eventually replaced—or eaten—by a bigger, badder master. At one point,
>   they followed the biggest amoeba—until he was devoured by an evil fish
>   who, in turn, was eaten by an evil amphibian. They followed that evil
>   lizard right out of the prehistoric sludge and onto a beach…   … where
>   he was smashed by a Tyrannosaurus rex.
>
> The Minions were very impressed. They stared in awe at the giant T.
>   rex, with his terrible claws and teeth. He was the greatest monster
>   they had ever seen—so much bigger and tougher than their other master.
>   It was love at first sight.

---

In regards your last point about the minions serving someone "nice", you may want to note that although the minions are generally played as funny/clueless, they show no qualms about committing some pretty heinous criminals acts such as burglary, assault, driving and flying without a licence, possessing controlled explosives and aiding and abetting the theft of a planetary body.